# Print user input in sequential order using for loop (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop

I would like to request for five numbers from the user and print the numbers in a list followed by the sum of the numbers:

i.e.

[image: number1: number2: number3: number4: number5: Sum:]

For my code it prints this instead,

[image: number: number1: number: number2:]

This is my code:

```
#prompt for 5 numbers 
x=1
num=0 
while True: 
    try: 
        sum = 0
        for y in range (1,6,1):
            num = int (input("number:"))
            sum = sum + num 
            print("number",x,":",num)
            x += 1 
        print ("Sum of numbers: ", sum)

    except ValueError: 
        print("Please enter a valid number")
        continue
```

How may I fix it such that it prints in a list instead?

Comment: remove `print("number",x,":",num)` ?

Comment: Don't use sum as a variable name since this masks the bultin function sum (which you could use in this case to sum the list of numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you meant

```
#prompt for 5 numbers 
x=1
num=0
while True: 
    try: 
        sum = 0
        for y in range (1,6,1):
            num = int (input("number "+str(x)+":"))
            sum = sum + num
            x += 1 
        print ("Sum of numbers: ", sum)
        x=1

    except ValueError: 
        print("Please enter a valid number")
        continue
```

Worked Example

```
number 1:2
number 2:5
number 3:4
number 4:8
number 5:1
Sum of numbers:  20
```

Comment: Hi, it is always better to include a working example also with your code.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
numbers = [int(input()) for _ in range(5)]
print(': '.join(map(lambda x: f'number{x}',numbers))+': Sum: '+str(sum(numbers)))
```

**Output:**

number1: number2: number3: number4: number5: sum: 15

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and it's quite simple, really

Rename `sum` to something else like `total`. Sum actually means something else(it is a keyword)

So your code should look like this-

```
#prompt for 5 numbers 
x=1
num=0 
while True: 
try: 
    total = 0
    for y in range (1,6,1):
        num = int (input("number:"))
        total += num 
        print("number",x,":",num)
        x += 1 
    print ("Sum of numbers: ", total)

except ValueError: 
    print("Please enter a valid number")
    continue
```